# Index out column vector of matrix and then multiply corresponding matrix

Tags: matlab

I have heavy computation as follows:

```
L = ones(100000,200000);
for i = 1:10000
    temp = f(i,...);
    L = L .* temp(:, index );
end
```

where `temp` is a **100,000*3 matrix** (values computed from `f(i,...)`; I omit arguments here) and `index` is a **1*200,000 integer vector** (1 to 3).

I have to do above many times in my algorithm. I feel Matlab wastes time creating 100000*200000 from `temp(:, index )` in the iteration. But, it may not necessary; that is, we can just extract corresponding column and then multiply to corresponding column of `L`. Yet, I cannot find a way to do it efficiently...

Hope anyone can give advice on this. Thanks!

I give a small and hypothetical example:

```
function test
x = rand(5,3);
t = rand(10,1); % could be very long
point = 3;
index = [1 2 1 3 2 3 1 2;...
         2 3 2 1 2 3 1 1;...
         1 1 1 2 2 3 1 1;...
         3 3 2 3 2 2 2 1;...
         2 3 2 1 2 1 3 1]; % could be very long
L = ones(10,8);
for i = 1:5
    temp = myfun(x(i,:),t,point);
    L = L .* temp(:, index(i,:) );
end
    function prob = myfun(x,t,point)
    prob = ones(size(t,1),point);
    for k = 2:point 
        prob(:,k) = exp( ((k-1).*x(1).*(t) + x(k) ));
    end
    de = sum(prob,2);
    for k = 1:point
        prob(:,k) = prob(:,k)./de;
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? Make a simple example with working code, you can change the nxm matrix to be 10x20 or so. That way I'll be able to help you.

Comment: You need to provide the full line for `f(i,...)` if you want to avoid the `temp` variable. I suggest you add an small illustrative example with hand calculated numbers.

Comment: if you have many zeros in your data consider using [sparse matrices](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)

Comment: I agree with @marco wassmer, for large matrices with many zero elements, sparse matrices save a lot of computation power.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's reply. I give a small example now. Actually, it does not contain zeros. So, sparse matrix may not come to rescue.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to save just some minor computation during each iteration, perhaps it makes a difference on your large matrices though. What I did was to change one line into `prob(:,k) = exp( ((k-1).*x(i,1).*(t) + x(i,k) ));`. Notice the elements in x. This saves some unnecessary computation. It is somewhat difficult to optimize this as I have no idea what this is, but here's my code:

```
x = rand(5,3);
t = rand(10,1);
point = 3;
index = [1 2 1 3 2 3 1 2;...
         2 3 2 1 2 3 1 1;...
         1 1 1 2 2 3 1 1;...
         3 3 2 3 2 2 2 1;...
         2 3 2 1 2 1 3 1];
L = ones(10,8);
for i = 1:5
    prob = ones(size(t,1),point);
    for k = 2:point 
        prob(:,k) = exp( ((k-1).*x(i,1).*(t) + x(i,k) ));
    end
    de = sum(prob,2);
    for k = 1:point
        prob(:,k) = prob(:,k)./de;
    end
    L = L .* prob(:, index(i,:) );
end
```

There are some dangerous operations I noticed, e.g. `de = sum(prob,2);`. Note that if you would change `prob(:,k) = prob(:,k)./de;` to `prob(:,k) = prob(:,k)./sum(prob,2);` you have a different result. Perhaps you're aware of this already, but it may be worth mentioning. Let me know if there is anything more I can do to help.

Comment: Thank you, @JCKaz. Actually, `myfun` is specified outside the algorithm. Above example I put it as a nested function for demonstration. After `profile on`, I found the line `L = L .* temp(:, index(i,:) );` is critical part of heavy computation. I think if we can tell Matlab to multiply the corresponding columns between `L` and  `temp(:, index(i,:) )` without actually (internally)  creating a matrix for `temp(:, index(i,:) )`. It should save time. But Matlab seems having no reference function or pointer like C++ or Fortran.

Comment: I see. But did you notice that `prob(:,k) = exp( ((k-1).*x(i,1).*(t) + x(i,k) ));` saves some computation as you don't need to first parse entire x vector, matrix, turn it into a vector and then extract one element. Now it simply gets the element immediately.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, I saw that. It indeed save time:) Do you have idea to `L = L .* temp(:, index(i,:) );`? It is critical part that I have to overcome.

Comment: Hmm, not off the top of my head. But if you try to explain what the problem you're solving is, then perhaps I can figure out a way to optimize a solution. Also, if my answer was somewhat helping, please upvote, I sure need the rep points :P

Comment: Also, if the answer is acceptable, you can click the checkbox to officially accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, JCKaz. I think the problem is `L = L .* temp(:, index(i,:) );`, so I am still thinking and waiting good solution to make it computationally fast. But I also appreciate your patient reply:)